# jQuery doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I set data with `jQuery.data()` but I couldn't get it later.
Code:

```
jQuery('#test').live('click', function() {
    alert(jQuery.data($(this), 'key'));
});
var element = jQuery('<div id="test">Test</div>');
jQuery.data(element, 'key', { test: "String" });
jQuery('body').append(element);
```

I'm using jQuery 1.5. Is this a bug (in jQuery `.live()`) or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried to append the div element to body before you set the data?

Comment: OT: `alert` sucks, use `console.log`

Comment: I use normally console.log but there might be users without a browser with a console (or they deactivated it) so an error could occur.

Comment: to get around that, use this code: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/source/browse/branches/firebug1.2/lite/firebugx.js?r=964 It will create a mock console object if it doesn't exist that will eliminate those errors.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel T. but I don't serve code with console code in it to a live site so I don't need that really :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#test').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).data('key'));
});
var element = $('<div id="test">Test</div>');
$(element).data('key', { test: "String" });
$('body').append(element);
```

Comment: +1, I prefer `alert($(this).data('key').test);` also `element` is already a jQuery object. here is a test [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/hZty3/) ;)